# One Exception Two Messages

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

When I get an exception in this code, I don't know why the exception message appears twice.
I'll try explain it better: a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

can Anyone help me?

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: If anything appears twice, it is probably called twice. Have you checked with a debugger, that the connection code is only called once?

Comment: did u check why the error is thrown?

Comment: The messages are separated (but not terminated) with `\r\n` so it appears at some point these are glued together and thrown. Perhaps the `OdbcConnection` is trying to provide additional details about the exception, but fetching those details gives another exception.

Comment: The cursor pass only one time over connection.open when the exception occurs and the error is thrown because I stopped the service. (for testing)

Comment: There will be infinite exceptions isn't it?

Comment: I'd imagine there will be one exception (with two identical lines in it) each time you try to open the connection.

Answer (score 2):

In the image you can see the newline between the Exception message. In the `OdbcConnection` class, the `CreateException()` method processes a `OdbcErrorCollection` of errors, and glues them together with a `Environment.NewLine` (code from .NET 4.0 System.Data):

```
internal static OdbcException CreateException(OdbcErrorCollection errors, ODBC32.RetCode retcode)
{
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (OdbcError odbcError in errors)
  {
    if (stringBuilder.Length > 0)
      stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    stringBuilder.Append(Res.GetString("Odbc_ExceptionMessage", (object) ODBC32.RetcodeToString(retcode), (object) odbcError.SQLState, (object) odbcError.Message));
  }
  return new OdbcException(((object) stringBuilder).ToString(), errors);
}
```

Apparently the underlying library runs into the same error twice, and then throws the (one) exception to you.

I don't know if there is anything you can do to prevent this, it doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with *your* code.

Comment: First of all thanks but sorry I don't understand what do you wanna I do, (sorry about  my engligh is not my strong point)... Do you wanna I pass the exception to the method you wrote? I can't find ODBC32...

Comment: The code I posted is from the `System.Data.OdbcConnection` code. It's part of the framework, and it shows how two errors can appear in one `Exception` object.

Comment: I _thought_ I understood what you're trying to do, but I wouldn't know what ODBC32 you are looking for or why you want to "find" it.

Comment: The problem is that when I paste the code in my class the compiler says: 'System.Data.Odbc.ODBC32' is inaccessible due to its protection level
'System.Data.Odbc.ODBC32.RetCode' is inaccessible due to its protection level
Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Data.Odbc.ODBC32.RetCode' is less accessible than method 'RPS.Generics.Data.OdbcTools.CreateException(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcErrorCollection, System.Data.Odbc.ODBC32.RetCode)'

Comment: The code in my post is copy pasted from the `System.Data` namespace, and shows how multiple error messages can end up in the same `Exception`. Copy pasting it has no use. As I said, I don't think there's anything wrong with _your_ code.

Comment: Allright there's no problem but I don't wanna be tiresome but why does it has one exception with two messages?

Comment: I don't know *exactly*, but apparently along the way the ODBC driver runs into the same _error_ twice and then throws _one exception_ containing both (equal) error messages. The code I posted just shows that the driver is capable of doing that, I did not find the reason why it does so in this specific case.